# How to optimize calculating large numbers in Python

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, out-of-memory

When calculating a large number in Python such as 2^(2^1000000), the program would run out of memory. Is there a way to break this calculation into smaller chunks so not as much memory gets used?

EDIT:
I only want to display a module of this number so I really only want to calculate the last 10 or so digits of the number.

Comment: You need to specify what language you are working in.  Welcome to Stack Overflow, you may want to review our [How to Ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) document.

Comment: This questions belongs more to Mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to compute all digits of this number, you will not just run out of memory, but run out of lifetime, even using all the computers in the universe.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. I only want the last 10 or so digits.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is to perform one million squarings of 2, modulo 10^10.

So it suffices to implement product modulo 10^10 (readily available with 64 bits arithmetic) and iterate.

If I am right, `7841627136`.

```
P= 2
for i in range(1000000):
    P= (P * P) % 10000000000
print P
```